# Changes to object properties not being reflected in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue component with a single prop, which is an object. When a property in this object is changed, it doesn't seem to be updating in the Vue template.

Here is a simplified version of the component:

```html
<template>
  <p>{{ item.quantity }}</p>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      item: {
        required: true,
        type: Object
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Using [vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) in Google Chrome, I can see the `quantity` property in my `item` object *is* being updated, but the template still only renders the default value (`1`).

Is there something I need to do to make Vue watch nested properties or something?

Comment: you can create a new object from the old one and then change the prop value, so the object ref changes

Comment: @h1b9b Could you explain more in an answer?

Comment: I am not a vue.js specialist but if the component checks only object ref (a == b) and not a deepEqual, you need a new object so it can detect the change. somme thing like newItem = {...item, quantity: newquantity } should work

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the component is not aware that it should re-render when there is a change in the props. You could use a computed property which returns the  props value and use the computed property value.

```
<template>
  <p>{{ quantity }}</p>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      item: {
        required: true,
        type: Object
      }
    }

    computed: {
        quantity: function() {
            return this.item.quantity
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried using a computed value, for both the `item` prop and specifically `item.quantity`, but the template still doesn't seem to update.

Comment: I understand your value is coming from the vuex store. Have you tried using `mapState` to get the state from the store? You could try using the `mapState` in the `computed` properties.

Comment: The component represents a single item from an array of items in the Vuex store. The item is a line item in an order. I'm trying to get the displayed quantity to update if that item's quantity is updated in the Vuex store.

Comment: So from what I understand there is a `parent component` that renders an array of item components. If the `parent component` is mapped to the Vuex store and passes the mapped values as props to the children, that would trigger a re-render of the children if the child uses the prop in computed or data.

Comment: This seems like the right approach.  There is also the deep watch option.   I just went through this same issue last week and my real problem was how I was updating the original array in vuex.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats